# Inflection points

Tags: calculus

I'm struggling to find a quadratic that will satisfy the question below:

Enter a quadratic polynomial $f(x)$ for which

$$f(x)+\frac{\ln(x)}{x^{3}}$$

has a stationary inflection point at $x=1$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the question has now been properly edited.

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a quadratic with arbitrary variables:

$$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$

Calculating the second derivative, we get:

$$f''(x) = 2a$$

Then calculating the second derivative for $\frac{\ln x}{x^3}$, it follows that it is:

$$f''(x) = \frac{12\ln x - 7}{x^5}$$

Therefore, our second derivative becomes:

$$f''(x) = 2a + \frac{12\ln x - 7}{x^5}$$

Since at $x=1$ we have an inflection point:

$$f''(1) = 2a  - 7 = 0$$

Therefore, in order for the conditions to be satisfied, we must have $a = \frac{7}{2}$

However, note that both $b$ and $c$ can be arbitrary values.

Thus, our answer is:

$$f(x) = \frac{7}{2}x^2 + bx + c$$

Where $b$ and $c$ are arbitrary values

Comment: Hey thanks for your contribution, it turns out only c is an arbitrary value. When solving for b, it turns out b must have a value of -8.

Cheers

Comment: @MatStrat okay. Happy to help :).

Comment: @MatStrat: For a stationay inflexion we need to have both $ y'= y''=0$ at x=1, is that correct? Like $ y= x^3 $ at $x=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Set $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Then find the second derivative and set it to zero at the given point.

Comment: I tried this and came up with a=0 at the second derivative. Im not quite sure what I am supposed to do with this value